# Dotnet Core, is Assembly.Load(string) idempotent?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've inherited some code that I think is a little odd, and want to make sure if it's a potential issue or not.

First, it gets the name of a loaded assembly based on a type it contains:

```
private readonly string _assemblyName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IEntityBase)).FullName;
```

Then, on each request to process a named entity, it loads the assembly by name, even though the assembly is already loaded:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(_assemblyName);
var type = assembly.GetType(entityFullName);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I'm wondering if the Load calls are potentially causing issues - in this case, since the assembly is already loaded, is the call idempotent and returns the already-loaded assembly, or does it create a new assembly each time?

Comment: What's even more odd is that that assembly is presumably already loaded... because you needed to load `typeof(IEntityBase)` from it! Why not just do `typeof(IEntityBase).Assembly.GetType(...)`

Comment: Ah. My thought was to do ```private readonly Assembly _entitiesAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IEntityBase))```, then use the referenced assembly to get the type. Your example would work as well, not sure which is more efficient and/or easier to understand.

Comment: Up to you -- they're functionally equivalent. The important bit is *not* doing `FullName`, and then using *that* to get the assembly which `IEntityBase` is in